# Merge sort algorithm is not functioning properly

Tags: c, sorting, merge, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

A merge sorting algorithm is not working as it is supposed to do. The output values are not fully sorted in the ascending order. Some of the values are out of order which is pointing to a bug.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int *L, int *R, int *a, int nL, int nR) {
    int i, j, k;
    i = j = k = 0;

    while ((i < nL) && (j < nL)) {
        if (L[i] < R[j]) {
            a[k] = L[i];
            ++i;
        } else {
            a[k] = R[j];
            ++j;
        }
        ++k;
    }

    while (i < nL) {
        a[k] = L[i];
        ++i;
        ++k;
    }

    while (j < nR) {
        a[k] = R[j];
        ++j;
        ++k;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;

    int i, mid, *L, *R;

    mid = n / 2;

    L = (int *)malloc(mid * sizeof(int));
    R = (int *)malloc((n - mid) * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < mid; ++i) {
        L[i] = a[i];
    }

    for (i = mid; i < n; ++i) {
        R[i - mid] = a[i];
    }

    mergeSort(L, mid);
    mergeSort(R, n - mid);

    merge(L, R, a, mid, n - mid);

    free(L);
    free(R);
}

int main() {
    int i, n, *a;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    a = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    mergeSort(a, n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

For example, for the following inputs: `10 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1`

I should get these outputs: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

But the outputs are not in the ascending order. The outputs are:`1 3 4 5 2 6 8 9 10 7`

Comment: the mergesort algorithm does not involve any calls to `malloc()` nor `free()`  Suggest reading: [mergesort algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/)

Comment: regarding: *I should get these outputs: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10*  The mergesort algorithm does NOT remove duplicates, so the output should be:  `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it covers all the problems but

```
while((i < nL) && (j < nL))
```

should be

```
while((i < nL) && (j < nR))
                        ^
                        note
```

Comment: Just looking is not enough. You need to debug, trace through, try various use cases. You need to split your code in pieces and put in back together.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion